# node.js & react - server not up, from github project

Tags: node.js, github, websocket, socket.io, yarnpkg

I found one project on GitHub [darkwire](https://github.com/darkwire/darkwire.io) and wanted to install it and play with it. Firstly I tried to install it from windows. I installed Node.js and Yarn and I got errors with the command: `yarn dev`

```
`C:\darkwire.io-master>yarn dev
yarn run v1.21.1
$ concurrently 'cd client && yarn start' 'cd server && yarn dev'
[0] 'c' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[1] 'client' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[1] operable program or batch file.
[0] c exited with code 1
[1] client exited with code 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`
```

My next step was to try it in ubuntu 19.10, firstly I installed again Node.js and Yarn and again used: `yarn dev`. I got an error but now was open site and it not working, just say `"Disconnected"`

````
```qq@ubuntu:~/Downloads/darkwire.io-master$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.21.1
$ concurrently 'cd client && yarn start' 'cd server && yarn dev'
$ nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node
$ react-scripts start
[1] [nodemon] 1.19.0
[1] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[1] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[1] [nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
[1] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
[1] Checking for inactive rooms...
[1] Darkwire is online at port 3001
[1] events.js:183
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
[1]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
[1] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[0] Starting the development server...
[0] 
[0] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
[0] Compiled successfully!
[0] 
[0] You can now view darkwire-client in the browser.
[0] 
[0]   Local:            http://localhost:3000/
[0]   On Your Network:  http://175.124.13.111:3000/
[0] 
[0] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[0] To create a production build, use yarn build.
[0]
```
````

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bijQI.jpg)

I think maybe I have the wrong version Node.js and try install 9.x version, download again project and try again, it not help, try change port from 3001 to 3000, not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their  [README.md](https://github.com/darkwire/darkwire.io/blob/master/readme.md)

> Darkwire Server
>   Darkwire server is a Node.js application that **requires redis.**

So please install a compatible redis server. [Redis tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/introduction-to-redis-install-cli-commands-and-data-types/)

Comment: thanks ! it help for me ! not seen this requirement.